# Semantic head finder with priority given to noun/noun phrases

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, semantics

Does anyone know of an implementation of a semantic head finder which gives priority to N*/NP's instead of V*/VP's?

I've been able to use the Stanford Tregex package to extract heads of NPs with the pattern `__ >># NP` but doing the same for `ROOT` will give a verb as the head phrase.

Comment: why not try dependency parser and find the VP's head? But in NP it's sort of strange because sometimes determiner is head of the main noun.

Comment: the semantic head is not necessarily the head of the main VP. For example, in `what year did the titanic sink`, I want to return `year` as the semantic head of the sentence.

Comment: Looking at the Stanford dependency parser, I might be able to use the nsubj constituent as the head with some further processing to find the real one. I'll experiment with that. Thanks for the info